# Minimal supersymmetric Standard Model Supersymmetry Breaking

Tags: supersymmetry, symmetry-breaking, beyond-the-standard-model, mssm

I'm working through Srednicki's QFT book.

I'm at Chapter 96 where he covers the Minimal Supersymmetric Standard Model.

I understand that supersymmetry is not an exact symmetry and I understand that Srednicki is using spurion analysis to handle the symmetry breaking.

The question I have is related to what Srednicki says near the bottom of page 622.

> "Correct phenomenology requires supersymmetry breaking to be triggered by fields other than those listed above [the fields in the MSSM]."

Does he say this because no one has noticed symmetry breaking among those fields (i.e. none of the fields listed acquire a nonzero VEV)?  Is there another reason?